# LINQ query - search components in system

Tags: linq

Hi

I have some problem building a good LINQ query, which can find systems –where the systems “contains” one or more parts. The parts have a referencepart, which the search is based on.

Database:

[Database image](http://web-tech.dk/Udklip.png)

Pseudo code:

Find systems where SystemPartCollection contains the systemId and all partId – which is linked to the following referenceId’s.

I got some SQL code... but i need it in linq

```
    -- specified ReferencePartID
DECLARE @p0 Int = 1
DECLARE @p1 Int = 3

-- number of destinct ReferencePartID
DECLARE @p2 Int = 2

SELECT *
FROM [System] AS [t0]
CROSS APPLY 
(
    SELECT max([t2].ReferencePartID) as maxID, [t2].ReferencePartID from [SystemPartCollection] AS [t1]
    INNER JOIN [Part] AS [t2] ON [t1].[PartID] = [t2].[PartID]
    WHERE 
    ([t0].[SystemID] = [t1].[SystemID] AND ([t2].[ReferencePartID] = @p0 OR [t2].[ReferencePartID] = @p1))
    GROUP BY [t2].ReferencePartID 
) partSearch
WHERE maxID >= @p2
```

Anyone?

Comment: Welcome to [SO]. What have you tried so far? ([SO] is not a code writing service.)

Comment: Sorry - i was not specific enough. I would like to be pointed in the "right" direction - on building this query. Do i count the parts in a sub-selection like in the sql example? I would like to keep the query in one round trip to the database.

Comment: If I had a SQL Query to do the job, and without very good reason, I would just continue to use that ("if it isn't broken, don't fix it"). (Use `DbContent.Database.SqlQuery<TResult>` to run it.) Anything else: the last part of my previous comment applies; you need to show what you have got so far *in LINQ* (too much variation otherwise in your entity types for anything other than guesses).